# Azure Function Core Tools does not link with my Conda environment

Tags: python, azure

I'm got a working respiratory of codes working on Azure in a function app (version 3). However, I can't get it running locally. The reason for this is (i think) because the Azure Core Tools doesn't link to my Conda environment.

When I run 'func start' the output first generates the following

```
(myenv) C:\mypath\__app__>func start
 Found Python version 3.8.0 (py).
```

This is odd because in myenv (conda environment) I have installed python 3.8.13, which is the version I need. The result of this difference in versions leads to multiple modules not being found.

Error message:

```
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.identity'.
```

I installed Core Tools v3

Comment: Refer to @Chris [Blog](https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-azure-identity/) to fix this `ModuleNotFoundError` .

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end we could able to make this work after installing the `azure.identity` in your environment.

```
pip install azure-identity
```

Also, make sure you install the packages in requirements.txt file by running the command

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```